# Define model relationships in complex business logic in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model

Now I have those business logic, but don't know how to define it in Laravel.

First, there are two basic model named `contact` and `project`, and `contact` and `project` model owns many-to-many relations so I defined them like below:

```
class Contact extends Model{
    public function projects(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project', 'proj_staff')
            ->withPivot('role', 'superior');
    }
}
```

And the same as `Project`:

```
class Project extends Model{
    public function contacts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'proj_staff')
            ->withPivot('role', 'superior');
    }
}
```

As you see, every `contact` has a `superior` in his `project` or not, so the question comes with it that how can I define a relation to get access to `superior` like this: `$contact->projects[0]->superiors`, and the `superiors` has better return a Model Collection rather than just `id`.

Thx any way.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing **`projects`** from your **`contacts`** & you want to access **`projects`** & **`contacts`** pivot table **`proj_staff`** info from your **`projects`** model.

> So you have to create another relation in your in your **`Project`**
>   model to access the data from your pivot table

```
class Project extends Model{
    public function contacts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'proj_staff')
            ->withPivot('role', 'superior');
    }

    //your project table has one to many many relationship with proj_staff table
    public function superiors(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProjStaff', 'superior', 'superior');//set relation keys I assume it's superior is local and foreign key
    }
}

//Create ProjStaff Pivot Table Model under app directory same level with your Contact model
class ProjStaff extends Model{
    //add fillable
    //add table name

}
```

> Now you can easily access superior like **`$contact->projects[0]->superiors->pluck('superior')->all()`**

Comment: And at the same times the superior is of `Contact` model, it is relations between two contacts but under a limitation of `Project`.In other words, `superior` is determined by both `Contact` and `Project`,some contact will be a superior of some contact in one project.